# Filling Datasets from Oracle within VB Threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, oracle

I'm trying to run a couple of PL/SQL procedures from within a VB app. The procedures take a while to run so I intend to put them into separate threads (the subject of which I am new to)

Currently, each thread calls a function, which in turn calls the following code:

```
' Function getDataSet
' builds a data set from given information
' Parameters:
'   aCommand - the PL/SQL procedure to call
'   aParamCollection - an oraParameterCollection object containing all the parameters
'   aDataSet - a data set to hold the results
' Returns:
'   number of rows retrieved

Public Function getDataSet( _
    ByVal aCommand As String, _
    ByVal aParamCollection As oraParameterCollection, _
    ByRef aDataSet As DataSet _
    ) As Integer

    Dim result As Integer = 0

    ' define commands etc
    Dim cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand(aCommand, dbConn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    ' add parameters for the query
    For i As Integer = 0 To aParamCollection.getParameterCount() - 1
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter( _
                                aParamCollection.getParameterByIndex(i).ParameterName, _
                                aParamCollection.getParameterByIndex(i).ParameterType)).Value = _
                                aParamCollection.getParameterByIndex(i).ParameterValue
    Next

    Dim param As OracleParameter = New OracleParameter("io_cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    CheckConnection()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim cur As OracleRefCursor
    cur = param.Value
    cmd.Dispose()

    Dim theAdaptr As New OracleDataAdapter

    If aDataSet IsNot Nothing Then
        theAdaptr.Fill(aDataSet, cur)
        result = aDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count
    End If

    Return result

End Function
```

Where:
aCommand = the PL/SQL proc to execute
aParamCollection = a custom class that holds parameters, types and values
aDataSet = the data set to hold the resulting data

However, when I run the app, I get an access violation at this point:

```
theAdaptr.Fill(aDataSet, cur)
```

I assume that the separate threads can't make the call to Fill at the same time, is this correct?  I am currently kicking off each thread as so:

```
    Dim th_Mean As New Thread(AddressOf getMeanData)
    Dim th_Stdev As New Thread(AddressOf getStdevData)

    th_Mean.Name = "th_Mean"
    th_Stdev.Name = "th_Stdev"

    th_Mean.Start()
    th_Stdev.Start()    

    Do While th_Mean.IsAlive Or th_Stdev.IsAlive
    Loop
```

Ultimately, my question is, what *should* I be doing so as to avoid the access violation happening?

Thanks for reading
BBz

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding the parallelism in the database?  Parallelism is (relatively) easy with declarative SQL.  Depending on your stored procedures, it may be as simple as finding the slow query and adding a hint, something like:

```
select /*+ parallel(my_table) */ * from my_table;
```

If the procedure is more about row-by-row processing than queries you may need to look into parallel pipelined functions.

Comment: Thx for the reply. The stored procs I am using are actually like this one I posted in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218345/solved-pl-sql-avg-function-with-vs2008-causing-arithmetic-operation-resulted-i  It's using AVG with DECODE to sort averages of data into columns based on a particular name. Running this query with dates of a year or more takes > 10 minutes to run (which is unreasonable w.r.t. what I'm trying to achieve above!)

Comment: There may be several ways to optimize that procedure:  Can you move the entire procedure to the remote database?  Distributed processing adds a lot of complexity, if you can perform as much of the processing as possible in the same place that may help things.  If all of the tables are local adding parallelism is easy, but I don't think you can parallelize across a database link.  Some of the Oracle documentation implies that distributed tables are usually pulled to the local instance and joined there.  Maybe the DRIVING_SITE hint can help?

Comment: Hi, thx again for the advice. Think I may go back to the drawing board on this and do the stats etc in client code (though I thought the whole point was to use the DB to do the work!) I don't think I have the option of putting the procs into the primary DB and to be honest, I haven't used hints before so that seems like a learning curve in itself (which I'm not averse to, but have more pressing things to focus on with this project.)